# Why "Disks" and "Startup Disk Creator" utilities don't work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: disk-utility, startup-disk-creator

I have problems with these utilities. When I try to format USB from **Disk Utility** I get this error:

> Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)

When I try to create bootable USB from **Startup Disk Creator** I get this:

> An uncaught exception was raised: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you try using **Gparted**. It's considered by many to be a standard, highly stable / respected tool for formatting drives. This command will install it if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now follow the steps:

1. Ensure you select the correct drive:
   [image]
   In GParted, select the flash drive from the dropdown menu in the top right corner.
2. Then select "Device" > "Create Partition Table". Choose MBR/DOS. After that you can format it...
3. Right click to unmount it. This allows you to change things on the disk because it stops the system from using it.
4. Once you have it unmounted, right clicking on it will show you the Format To option. You can choose whatever type of file system you want on the disk.
5. Click Apply

To do this with more pictures and info, try looking at [my source here](http://itsfoss.com/how-to-format-a-sd-card-or-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-12-10/).

Personally, I don't think you can say Linux is "better" than Windows because it's to complicated to make a straight comparison. I happen to far favor Linux and Linux has many strengths that Windows does not. However, as with everything, when you come to something new you might need to learn about your new toolset before you can work as easily.

Gparted is part of your new toolset.

Finally, you might be able to **fix the bug in the tools you tried** to used with an update. [From launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/util-linux/+bug/1059872):

> This bug was fixed in the package udisks2 - 2.1.3-2git1ubuntu1

You can update your system with `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Hello Palu Macil i wanted to say that Linux system is know for its reliability  ,and that tools works not like in windows if you know what i mean. I;m familiar with gpart and i use it. Anyway 10x for the info

Comment: @IvanIvanov Since I pointed out the specific bug number and everything, would you consider marking this as the answer? :)